# Why would the existence of a file affect how its filepath is parsed in a batch script?

Tags: batch-file

There's something I'm not understanding about the way that the batch `for` command works, when used with `/f` and a command.

I was trying to loop on the output of an executable.  The executable turned out to not exist, which is fine.

But instead of getting the expected error about a bad path, the script seemed to spontaneously incorrectly tokenize the string.  This led me down a rabbit hole of thinking that I had formatted the for loop and/or used quotes or back-ticks incorrectly.

Placing an executable at the location fixes the issue, making it appear like the path string tokenizing is dependent on the existence of an actual file at that path.

Why does the following batch file

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ( `"C:\Program Files\BOGUS_PATH\FAKE.exe"`) do (
    rem
)
```

output `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` instead of `The system cannot find the path specified.` ?

Comment: it works, when you escape the space(s): `for /f "delims=" %%i in ("C:\Program^ Files\BOGUS_PATH\FAKE.exe") do echo %%i`. (please don't ask me why...)

Comment: @Stephan - That is a totally different statement - your code tries to read a file, and gives that message because the file cannot be found. The escape serves no purpose - you get the same result without it. The OP's code is trying to execute a command.

Comment: @dbenham lost the `'` during editing: `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('"C:\Program^ Files\BOGUS_PATH\FAKE.exe"') do echo %%i`

Comment: @Stephan - Whoa, that is freaky. I am shocked that works. You don't need the FOR /F or the quotes. This works from the command line: `c:\program^ files\bogus_path\fake.exe`. That is the first case I have ever seen where you can escape a token delimiter like that. But remove the leading `c:` and the escape does not work, which is what I expect in all cases. I learned something today, thanks.

Comment: @Stephan - Without quotes in a FOR loop you need `for /f "delims=" %%I in ('c:\program^^^ files\bogus_path\fake.exe') do ...` because there are two rounds of parsing, so you need to escape the escape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, a pet peeve of mine, the `usebackq` is not needed. The simpler and functionally equivalent command is

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('"C:\Program Files\BOGUS_PATH\FAKE.exe"') do (
    rem
)
```

The only time `usebackq` is required is when you are trying to read a file, and the file path contains token delimiters like space.

```
for /f "usebackq" %%A in ('"some file.txt"')
```

All other situations can use the "normal" forms

```
for /f %%A in (fileName) do...
for /f %%A in ("string") do...
for /f %%A in ('someCommand') do...
```

---

Now to answer your actual question :-)

The presence or absence of the file does not actually alter the parsing.

First you need to understand the possible error messages when you try to execute a non-existent program from the command line. There are three possibilities:

1) If the "command" includes a colon anywhere other than the 2nd position, then you may get the following

```
c:\test\>abc:fake.exe
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

c:\test\>abc:\test\fake.exe
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Or sometimes you get the next possible error. The rules as to which message you get are not obvious to me, and I don't feel like it is important enough to figure out the exact rules.

2) If the "command" includes a backslash that indicates a path, and the path is not valid, then you get

```
c:\test\>c:bogus\fake.exe
The system cannot find the path specified.

c:\test\>\bogus\fake.exe
The system cannot find the path specified.

c:\test\>abc:bogus\fake.exe
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

3) If the executable file cannot be found, and either the "command" does not include path info or the provided path is valid, then you get

```
C:\test\>fake.exe
'fake.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\test>c:\test\fake.exe
'c:\test\fake.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

---

The last conundrum is why `"C:\Program Files\BOGUS_PATH\FAKE.exe"` gives error 3) instead of 2)

If you execute from the command line with quotes then you get the expected result:

```
C:\test>"C:\Program Files\BOGUS_PATH\FAKE.exe"
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

If you execute from the command line without quotes, then you get this expected result:

```
C:\test>C:\Program Files\BOGUS_PATH\FAKE.exe
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Your script includes quotes, so you would expect the former, but you get the latter.

There are two parts to understanding this.

First off, FOR /F executes the command by executing

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files\BOGUS_PATH\FAKE.exe"
```

You might think your "command" is quoted, but cmd.exe plays games with quotes, which is the 2nd part to the explanation. The cmd.exe quote rules are described in the help:

```
c:\test\>help cmd
Starts a new instance of the Windows command interpreter
...
If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
used to process quote (") characters:

    1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
        on the command line are preserved:

        - no /S switch
        - exactly two quote characters
        - no special characters between the two quote characters,
          where special is one of: &<>()@^|
        - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
          two quote characters
        - the string between the two quote characters is the name
          of an executable file.

    2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
        a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
        remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
        any text after the last quote character.
```

Most of the conditions under `1.` are met ***except*** for the last one - the string does not point to a valid executable. So the `2.` rules are used, thus the command becomes

```
C:\Program Files\BOGUS_PATH\FAKE.exe
```

And now the result makes perfect sense - the "command" breaks at the space.

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

---

If you are trying to execute a command with `FOR /F`, and the command must be enclosed within quotes, then you must put an extra set of quotes around the entire command.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('""c:\some path\file.exe" "arg 1" arg2"') do ...
```

But the above will have problems if there are poison characters in the path or quoted argument, because the extra set of quotes mess up the quoting. You could escape the poison characters like

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('""c:\some path\file.exe" "this^&that" arg2"') do ...
```

But I find that awkward because the command you use on the command line does not match the command you use in a `FOR /F`. I prefer to escape the extra set of enclosing quotes so that whatever works on the command line also works within `FOR /F`.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('^""c:\some path\file.exe" "this&that" arg2^"') do ...
```

Comment: Well, this certainly explains why the error message is `'C:\Program' is not recognized...` when the file does not exist.  However, this does not explain why there is no `'C:\Program' is not recognized...` error message when the file does exist.

Comment: @cowlinator - Actually it does. If the file does exist, then the rule set 1 is used, so the quotes are preserved and the file is found and executed.

Comment: Ok, so the short of it is: The presence of the file does not alter the parsing.  The presence of the file alters whether quote characters are preserved or stripped.  Wait, isn't that parsing?

Answer (score 3):

**FOR** is an internal command of Windows command processor `cmd.exe`. The usage of command **FOR** with option `/F` and a command to execute results in starting with `%ComSpec% /c` and the specified command line as further parameter(s) one more command process running in background.

Everything output to handle **STDOUT** is captured by current command process executing the batch file with command **FOR** and is processed by **FOR** after termination of additionally started `cmd.exe` line by line.

The output to handle **STDERR** of additionally started command process is redirected to handle **STDERR** of current command process resulting in getting it displayed in console window in case of **STDERR** is neither in additionally started command process nor in current command process redirected to a different handle, file or device **NUL**.

This can be seen on using free Sysinternals (Microsoft) tool [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

- Download the ZIP file containing *Process Monitor*.
- Extract the ZIP file into any local directory.
- Start `Procmon.exe` with *Run as administrator* which is required to run *Process Monitor*.
- In **Process Monitor Filter** dialog displayed first **Add** the entry **Process Name is cmd.exe** and close the dialog with button **OK**.
- Toggle off the last five options on toolbar with the exception of the filling cabinet symbol with the tooltip *Show File System Activity*.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> to clear the list.
- Run the batch file.
- Switch back to *Process Monitor* and press <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd> to stop capturing.
- Make sure to see among the column **Process Name** also the column **PID**. Right click on list header and left click on context menu item **Select Columns...** if the **PID** column is not already displayed, check **Process ID** and close dialog window with **OK**. I recommend to move the column **PID** using drag and drop of column header **PID** right to column **Process Name**.

Scroll up to begin of list of captured file system activities and look for the line where a `cmd.exe` with a different process identifier is displayed than the first one. That second `cmd.exe` with different PID is the Windows command processor instance started by **FOR**.

Right click on this second `cmd.exe`, left click in context menu on **Properties**, select tab **Process** and look on **Command Line** showing:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files\BOGUS_PATH\FAKE.exe"
```

Okay. So we know now what **FOR** respectively `cmd.exe` does on running a command to capture the output of this command. Close the properties window.

Look on list and it can be seen which file system accesses are made by second `cmd.exe` to find the specified executable which does not exist in specified and existing directory. It searches next for `C:\Program Files\BOGUS_PATH\FAKE.exe.*` also with no such file as result.

The first argument string is split up now on argument separators to which belongs the space character among some others like comma or equal sign. So the first argument string `C:\Program Files\BOGUS_PATH\FAKE.exe` is argument separated once more resulting in interpreting `C:\Program` now as first argument string.

`cmd.exe` checks if the directory path being now just `C:\` is existing which is true like it was before for directory path `C:\Program Files\BOGUS_PATH`.

Next is checked if there is a file matching the pattern `C:\Program.*` which returns no such file. Then `cmd.exe` checks if there is the file `C:\Program` which again results in no such file.

Now second `cmd.exe` gives up finding a file which could be executed and outputs the error message.

It is indeed confusing on having specified the executable with full path enclosed in double quotes as required because of the space to get not output

> 'C:\Program Files\BOGUS_PATH\FAKE.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command
>   operable program or batch file.

This would be expected, but output is the error message:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command
>   operable program or batch file.

I think, parsing the first argument string once again using the argument separators on not finding a file to execute is done for example if a user runs `cmd.exe` with the command (argument)

```
"C:\Programs\MyApplication.exe C:\Temp\FileToProcess.txt"
```

instead of

```
"C:\Programs\MyApplication.exe" "C:\Temp\FileToProcess.txt"
```

So the question is:

Is this automatic argument parsing good or not good?

Well, this is difficult to answer. It is at least somehow documented in help of `cmd.exe` as described by [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55985953/3074564).

Comment: So, you're saying that it first searches for `C:\Program Files\BOGUS_PATH\FAKE.exe.*` without trying to parse it into arguments; and only if it then doesn't find anything, it tries to parse the string into arguments using space as an arg separator?  So, in the case that the file doesn't exist, it only gives the `'C:\Program' is not recognized...` error because it had already tried evaluating the whole string as a single path and failed, but that first error didn't get printed.  That explains why the parsing behavior appears different when the file doesn't exist: it tried more parsing options.

Comment: @cowlinator - Based on the rules documented for cmd.exe, it cannot know at the beginning whether the quotes should be stripped or not. All the conditions for rule set 1 are met until the last one. So it must search for the entire given quoted path. If it was found it would be executed. But upon not finding it, cmd.exe assumes (by design) that the quotes should be stripped according to rule set 2. The path gets split at the space, the `c:\program` is neither an external executable nor an internal command, and the error is spawned.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need to do is to enclose your executable command in doublequotes:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('""C:\Program Files\BOGUS_PATH\FAKE.exe""'
)Do Echo(%%A
Pause
```

*Where the inner set of doublequotes is to protect the known space in the path, and the outer set to protect the inner ones when the content is passed to the `cmd.exe` instance, that the parenthesised command is run in.*

Then to prevent any error message from the command, you should redirect the `STDERR` output to `NUL`:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('""C:\Program Files\BOGUS_PATH\FAKE.exe" 2>Nul"'
)Do Echo(%%A
Pause
```

If the executable does not exist, this will supress the error message, `The system cannot find the path specified.` and the `Do` command will not run, *(as there is no `STDOUT` to process)*.